# Make an existing folder of source only files a new project (Apache NetBeans)

Tags: git, github, netbeans

I've successfully cloned a github repository to my local machine. The folder created on my machine has the project name (EQuakeVis), which is exactly what I wanted.

Since the repository I cloned is source files only, I can't use the "Open Project" option in NetBeans. The NetBeans specific project files aren't there.

When the cloning process was done, NetBeans gave me a wonderful dialogue asking me if I want to create a project using the newly cloned repo. However, because the project name I want to use is the very same name as the cloned repo (EQuakeVis), I can't create the project as the folder already exists and is not empty.

So, option one is to create a new project and copy and paste all the source files... Which isn't dreadfully hard, but is somewhat annoying.

I'm hoping someone has figured out option 2?

**Command Line Solution:**

1. Create empty NetBeans project with desired name.
2. git init
3. git pull (GitHub URL) (Branch)
4. git push --set-upstream (GitHub URL)

Seems to be the non-NetBeans solution that works best. I'm just hoping to learn a little more about my IDE and how to make it work for me.

Comment: Doesn't Netbeans have a "Create project with existing sources" option or the like?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Indeed it does, but the same problems listed in my question plague it. Namely, the fact that cloning a repository automatically puts a folder on your machine that happens to be the project name. So, you get the error message "That folder already exists and it is not empty".